# Regexp Replace - Append String to Second Occurrence Using R's Sub

Tags: r, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to append a string to the second occurance. The below code will replace the second occurrence with a static replacement string, but I need it to be flexible because the match can be, for example, either `(cat|dog)`. Below is what I'm using to replace with a static string `fish`.

```
string <- "xxx cat xxx cat xxx cat"
sub('^((.*?cat.*?){1})cat', "\\1\\fish", string, perl=TRUE)

[1]'xxx cat xxx fish xxx cat'
```

But what I'm trying to get is:

```
string <- "xxx cat xxx cat xxx cat"
sub('^((.*?(cat|dog).*?){1})(cat|dog)', "\\1<span>\\1</span>", string, perl=TRUE)

[1] xxx cat xxx <span>cat</span> xxx cat
```

or

```
string <- "xxx dog xxx dog xxx dog"
sub('^((.*?(cat|dog).*?){1})(cat|dog)', "\\1<span>\\1</span>", string, 

[1] xxx dog xxx <span>dog</span> xxx dog
```

Comment: The simplest would probably be `sub('(.*?cat|dog.*?)(cat|dog)', '\\1<span>\\2</span>', string)`, but that will just find the second occurrence of either. You can refer back to previously captured strings within the regex, but it gets a little complicated.

Comment: I have no experience with R, but: You are already using a capture group for the first part that you do not want to change (capture groups are enclosed in brackets -> `(capture group)`. Just use a capture group for the second part (the cat number 2) too. If it is like in most languages, all you need to do is use a second capture group . You are using `\1` in replace, use `\2` (or maybe `\3`) too (\1 should be the first capture group, \2 the second and so on). Careful though, your `(cat|dog)` regex will match `xxx dog xxx cat xxx cat` too...

Comment: Not sure, try http://ideone.com/wtpy5T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient or concise regex but I find it easier to understand this way:

```
sub('^(.*?)(cat|dog)(.*?)(cat|dog)', '\\1\\2\\3<span>\\4</span>', string, perl=TRUE)
```

The `{1}` in your regex is not needed. With your syntax (nested capturing groups) but without the `{1}`, here is what you could use:

```
sub('^(.*?(cat|dog).*?)(cat|dog)', '\\1<span>\\3</span>', string, perl=TRUE)
```

Note that those regex do not check that the same word (car or dog) is matched both times.

Comment: I actually just found through trial and error from your first response that '\\1<span>\\3</span>' worked for me. Thank you!