# Replace 'from nth to the last' occurrence of word in string/text

Tags: r, regex, stringr

[This question has been asked previously but hasn't been answered to the asker's satisfaction.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368712/how-to-use-stringrs-replace-all-function-to-replace-specific-matches-in-a-str)

Given the following string:

```
mystring <- "one fish two fish red fish blue fish"
```

The following function allows to replace the nth occurrence of a word in it:

```
replacerFn <- function(String, word, rword, n){
 stopifnot(n >0)
  pat <- sprintf(paste0("^((.*?\\b", word, "\\b.*?){%d})\\b",
           word,"\\b"), n-1)
  rpat <- paste0("\\1", rword)
  if(n >1) { 
    stringr::str_replace(String, pat, rpat)
   } else {
    stringr::str_replace(String, word, rword)
    }
 }


 replacerFn(mystring, "fish", "dog", 1)
 #[1] "one dog two fish red fish blue fish"
 replacerFn(mystring, "fish", "dog", 2)
 #[1] "one fish two dog red fish blue fish"
 replacerFn(mystring, "fish", "dog", 3)
 #[1] "one fish two fish red dog blue fish"
 replacerFn(mystring, "fish", "dog", 4)
 #[1] "one fish two fish red fish blue dog"
```

How do we have to adjust this function to replace the nth to last occurrence of the word?

2nd to last:

```
"one fish two dog red dog blue dog"
```

3rd to last:

```
"one fish two fish red dog blue dog"
```

and so on ...?

I tried things like str_replace_all or adjusting the regex part {1,} but without success.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add `n <- str_count(mystring, '\\w+') - n` in the function

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? I don't see how counting the number of words and subtracting the nth position from it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easier option with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
replacerFn2 <- function(String, word, rword, n) {

  p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) if (count >= n) rword else x) 
   gsubfn(word, p, String)
 }

replacerFn2(mystring, "fish", "dog", 2)
#[1] "one fish two dog red dog blue dog"

replacerFn2(mystring, "fish", "dog", 3)
#[1] "one fish two fish red dog blue dog"
replacerFn2(mystring, "fish", "dog", 4)
#[1] "one fish two fish red fish blue dog"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works ... guess the take-away lesson here is that you can pass a function into gsub too... I think that also works with some of the stringr functions ... 
`this` just refers to all the other parameters passed into `replacerFn2` right?

Comment: @meier_flo it is `gsubfn` instead of `gsub`.  The `this` is from a `proto` function which is similar in syntax to some other languages

Answer (score 1):

Your function is rather complex, with conditions. An alternative approach is to split the string into a character vector of individual words, apply `stringr` functions on it, then join it back into a single string:

```
library(stringr)

replace_function <- function(string, word, rword, n) {
  vec <- unlist(strsplit(string, " "))
  vec[str_which(vec, word)[n]] <- rword
  str_c(vec, collapse = " ")
}

replace_function(mystring, "fish", "dog", 1)
[1] "one dog two fish red fish blue fish"

replace_function(mystring, "fish", "dog", 2)
[1] "one fish two dog red fish blue fish"
```

Now, you can modify this function very easily to replace the nth element from the end, using `rev()`:

```
replace_end_function <- function(string, word, rword, n) {
  vec <- unlist(strsplit(string, " "))
  vec[rev(str_which(vec, word))[n]] <- rword
  str_c(vec, collapse = " ")
}

replace_end_function(mystring, "fish", "dog", 1)
[1] "one fish two fish red fish blue dog"

replace_end_function(mystring, "fish", "dog", 2)
[1] "one fish two fish red dog blue fish"
```

---

**Edit (my bad for thinking that "nth to last" meant "nth from last"):**

To replace *the nth to the last* element:

```
replace_end_function <- function(string, word, rword, n) {
  vec <- unlist(strsplit(string, " "))
  vec[str_which(vec, word)[n:length(str_which(vec, word))]] <- rword
  str_c(vec, collapse = " ")
}

replace_end_function(mystring, "fish", "dog", 1)
[1] "one dog two dog red dog blue dog"

replace_end_function(mystring, "fish", "dog", 2)
[1] "one fish two dog red dog blue dog"

replace_end_function(mystring, "fish", "dog", 3)
[1] "one fish two fish red dog blue dog"

replace_end_function(mystring, "fish", "dog", 4)
[1] "one fish two fish red fish blue dog"
```

Comment: Sorry, I might have not expressed myself clearly enough ... what I actually meant was 'from the nth occurrence all through to the last occurrence' the changes should be made ... e.g. from the 2nd occurrence all following ones:
 `"one fish two dog red dog blue dog`

Comment: Ooohhh, ok, I see. Even though there is an accepted answer already, I'll update my answer to match that. Should be easy

Comment: Sorry for not reading your question properly: I edited my answer and I also removed the duplicate flag: it is actually a different question and I was just wrong because I read too fast

Comment: I had understood 'nth to last' as meaning the 'nth from last'

Comment: Not that wasn't your fault ... that was my mistake ... I wasn't specific enough! Thanks for the answer anyways! One can only learn from seeing other options too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` within your function `replacerFn`, i.e.,

```
replacerFn <- function(String, word, rword, n) {
  v <- unlist(strsplit(String,split = " "))
  v[grep(word,v)[n:length(v)]] <- rword
  return(paste0(v,collapse = " "))
}
```